# Ant - conditional statement

Tags: ant, build-process, build-automation

I'm using ant to build my app, and I want to have single process for dev/qa/prod versions of the app. I want to do be able to specify the build target from command line:

```
ant -Dbuildtarget=dev|qa|prod
```

and in build.xml check for the value of *buildtarget* and set an application specific base URL property based on the *buildtarget* specified by the user. I will subsequently set the correct runtime param using

```
    <copy file="pre.app.properties" tofile="./app.properties" overwrite="true">
        <filterset>
            <filter token="BASE_URL" value="${baseurl}" />
        </filterset>
    </copy>
```

What I am stuck on is how to express this in and build.xml  ?

```
if buildtarget=='dev' 
    baseurl="http://my_dev_url"
else if buildtarget=='qa' 
    baseurl="http://my_qa_url"
else if buildtarget=='prod' 
    baseurl="http://my_prod_url"
```

I've searched around, but this seems to be difficult to do in ant.  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try using the [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) task of ant?

Answer (score 2):

When starting your ant script with ant -Dbuildtarget=dev|qa|prod it's as simple as =

```
<project >
  <property name="baseurl" value="http://my_${buildtarget}_url"/>
  <echo>$${baseurl} => ${baseurl}</echo>
</project>
```

The buildtarget property can be used as dynamic part of the baseurl property.
Afterwards ${buildurl} can be used for further processing..